# Can I add a custom modbar button?

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I have a function that auto scales the y axis. It takes in the figure and relayout data objects and then spits out a y axis that fits some criteria that I pre-determined. I want to add a new modbar button in dash plotly on python that fires the function and updates the figure any time I click on it. Is that possible?

One simple example would be to be able to resize the chart, but only reset the y-axis. The resize button that comes in the modbar out of the box resets the y axis and sets autosize = true. The example custom modbar button for the purpose of this question would do the first function, but not the second.

Comment: Please add an example to your question.

Comment: I went ahead and added an example

Comment: It sounds like 2 questions, I answered the first part _how to add a custom modbar button?_, if you need more help on how to trigger relayout/autoscale in python when user interacts, I suggest you open another one.

Answer (score 1):

Adding/removing/customizing modebar buttons is quite simple, one just need to define the figure [`config`](https://plotly.com/python/configuration-options/#configuration-options) accordingly using the `modeBarButtonsToAdd` and/or `modeBarButtonsToRemove` options (documented [here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/src/plot_api/plot_config.js#L300)).

Note that these configuration options are consistent across dash, plotly.py and plotly.js.

> The `.show()` method that you use to display your figures also accepts a
> `config` parameter.
>
> You can set the configuration options for your figure by passing a
> dictionary to this parameter which contains the options you want to
> set.

With Dash, the same config dictionary can be passed to the config property of a [`dcc.Graph`](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/graph?#graph-properties) component :

```py
dcc.Graph(figure=go.Figure(), config=config)
```

Here is a Plotly.js live example which removes the pre-defined 'autoscale2d' button and add a custom one with a specific handler that triggers [`Plotly.relayout()`](https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotlyrelayout) :

```js
const data = [{
  mode: 'lines',
  x: [-2, 0, 2],
  y: [2, -2, 3], 
  line: {shape: 'spline'}
}]

const layout = { title: 'Mode Bar Custom Button' }

const config = {
  displayModeBar: true,
  modeBarButtonsToRemove: ['autoscale2d'],
  modeBarButtonsToAdd: [{
    name: 'autoscale2d-custom',
    title: 'Autoscale (custom)',
    icon: Plotly.Icons.autoscale,
    click: function(gd) {
      Plotly.relayout(gd, {
        'xaxis.range': [-3, 3],
        'yaxis.range': [-3, 3]
      });
    }
  }]
}

Plotly.newPlot('graph', data, layout, config)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.16.2.min.js"></script>
<div id="graph"></div>
```