# adding a reset or clear button in modebar in plotly

Tags: python, graphics, plotly

I am using `plotly` to show some interactive graphics where the user can draw lines, and other figures. I can see that there is `eraseshape` button, but am wondering if it is possible to incorporate a button in modebar to remove all the selections on the chart all at once. For instance, if I use lasso or box select, I am not able to reverse it unless I double click it.

One way to do this is to create an independent reset button and attach a callback, but I'd like to have something in the modebar instead.

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.iris()

fig = px.scatter(df, x='petal_width', y='sepal_length', color='species')

fig.update_layout(
    dragmode='drawopenpath',
    newshape_line_color='cyan',
    title_text='Draw a path to separate versicolor and virginica'
)

fig.show(config={'modeBarButtonsToAdd': ['drawline',
                                        'drawopenpath',
                                        'drawclosedpath',
                                        'drawcircle',
                                        'drawrect',
                                        'eraseshape', 'resetScale2d'
                                       ]})
```

[image]

Comment: You would need a JavaScript callback in any case. The thing is that you [can't do this from Plotly.py right now](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/2114). You can with Plotly.js though, example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74670205/2529954).